# Variadic template parameter inference with nested maps

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, type-inference, template-argument-deduction

Working in C++, there's some times I'm working with nested maps. For instance, hypothetically:

```
enum Color { RED, GREEN, BLUE};
enum Shape { CIRCLE, SQUARE, TRIANGLE };
std::unordered_map<Color, std::unordered_map<Shape, int>> shapeColorCount;
```

For these situations, it would be useful to use variadic templates to write setter and getter functions that are templated over the types of the keys. The goal would be something like:

```
template<typename TValue, typename TKeys...>
TValue& nestedGet(MapTypeHere t_map, const TKeys&... t_keys);
void nestedSet(MapTypeHere t_map, const TValue& t_value, const TKeys&... t_keys);
```

It's not too hard to define these functions recursively, but my main problem is getting the type inference for the template parameters to work correctly. The problem is specifying MapTypeHere. I can almost write something like

```
template<typename TValue, typename TKey>
using Map = std::unordered_map<TKey, TValue>;

template<typename TValue, typename TOuterKey, typename... TInnerKeys>
using Map = std::unordered_map<TOuterKey, Map<TValue, TInnerKeys...>;

template<typename TValue, typename... TKeys>
TValue& nestedGet(Map<TValue, TKeys...>& t_map, const TKeys&... t_keys);
void nestedSet(Map<TValue, TKeys...>& t_map, const TValue& t_value, const TKeys&... t_keys);
```

Trying to create a recursive using directive, but it complains that I'm trying to use a parameter pack in a non-pack template variable when it attempts to use the base case for `Map`. If I wrap them in structs, it seems to allow it to do this recursive using declaration, but then I have a problem where the type inference doesn't work. Going back to the above example:

```
std::unordered_map<Color, std::unordered_map<Shape, int>> shapeColorCount
nestedSet<int, Color, Shape>(shapeColorCount, 5, Color::RED, Shape::SQUARE); // This works
nestedSet(shapeColorCount, 5, Color::RED, Shape::SQUARE); // It can't figure out the types for the template
```

Is there a way to get this setup working correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can write the following functions:

```
template<typename Map, typename Value, typename FirstKey, typename ...RestKeys>
void nestedSet(Map& map, Value const& value, FirstKey const& key, RestKeys const&... rest_keys)
{
    if constexpr(sizeof...(RestKeys) == 0)
        map[key] = value;
    else
        nestedSet(map[key], value, rest_keys...);
}

template<typename Map, typename FirstKey, typename ...RestKeys>
auto& nestedGet(Map& map, FirstKey const& key, RestKeys const&... rest_keys)
{
    if constexpr(sizeof...(RestKeys) == 0)
        return map[key];
    else
        return nestedGet(map[key], rest_keys...);
}
```

Note that this solution doesn't depend on a particular `unordered_map<Color, std::unordered_map<Shape, int>>` instantiation. It works for any instantiations of key and value types, and for any depth of nested `unordered_map`s.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/54qvfM).

Also, if you don't have c++17, then you can rewrite the `if constexpr` solution with an overloaded template that takes a single `KeyType` parameter.

Comment: Interesting. Suggests I was doing something too complicated by trying to construct the type Map directly because in principle it's inferrable from FirstKey, RestKeys, and Value instead of just taking Map directly. Is there any way to construct static assertions that will ensure that Map has the correct internal structure?

I suppose if you attempt to call the function with mismatched map structure and arguments, it'll fail to instantiate at some point, like trying to call operator[] on a primitive or with an incorrect variable type.

Comment: Yes exactly, you'll get an error message either way. You could write static_asserts if you want a custom error message.

Answer (score 4):

Is too late to play?

It seems to me that, given a recursive `nestedGet()`, that you can write using `if constexpr` (if you can use C++17) or also using overloading as follows,

```
template <typename M, typename K>
auto & nestedGet (M & map, K const & key)
 { return map[key]; }

template <typename M, typename K, typename ... RKs>
auto & nestedGet (M & map, K const & key, RKs const & ... rks)
 { return nestedGet(map[key], rks...); }
```

the `nestedSet()` function can be written upon `nestedGet()` simply as follows

```
template <typename M, typename V, typename ... Ks>
void nestedSet (M & map, V const & value, Ks const & ... keys)
 { nestedGet(map, keys...) = value; }
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

enum Color { RED, GREEN, BLUE};
enum Shape { CIRCLE, SQUARE, TRIANGLE };

template <typename M, typename K>
auto & nestedGet (M & map, K const & key)
 { return map[key]; }

template <typename M, typename K, typename ... RKs>
auto & nestedGet (M & map, K const & key, RKs const & ... rks)
 { return nestedGet(map[key], rks...); }

template <typename M, typename V, typename ... Ks>
void nestedSet (M & map, V const & value, Ks const & ... keys)
 { nestedGet(map, keys...) = value; }

int main () 
 {
   std::unordered_map<Color, std::unordered_map<Shape, int>> shapeColorCount;

   nestedSet(shapeColorCount, 42, Color::RED, Shape::SQUARE); 

   std::cout << nestedGet(shapeColorCount, Color::RED, Shape::SQUARE) << std::endl; 
 }
```

Comment: It's never too late :) This looks great. Could you add a demo just so it's easier to see that it works? Looks ok, but a demo would be nice.

Comment: @cigien - Why not? Example added.

Comment: This seems like it would also work. One failed version I tried before making this question was based on a very similar set of getters and setters, but without taking the type M as a template parameter. I kept thinking "Ah, but surely it should be possible to determine valid values of M once you know V and Ks", which is in principle possible but not actually necessary for my purposes. Thank you!

Comment: @NathanPierson - Exactly: given that you have only to set/get values in/from it, for you is enough intercept it as a generic type. And this way your getter/setter work also for `std::map`, `std::vector`, `std::array`, `std::deque`, not only for `std::unordered_map`.